# mod rewrite clicking link adds page to end of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ product.php?id=$1&cat=$2&name=$3
```

My URL looks like this (localhost):

```
localhost/website/product/123/categoryname123/productname123/
```

When I click any links on the product page such as home.php it shows this:

```
 localhost/website/product/123/categoryname123/productname123/home.php
```

I have added a forward slash to home link - /home.php
Now the link goes to:

```
localhost/home.php NOT localhost/website/home.php
```

Without having to change all my URL's to /website/home.php how can I fix this?

Comment: or will this work fine once its on a domain name? will / be enough once one a domain name or will i need to change links to website.com/home.php etc?

Comment: That's the problem with relative paths in your links. btw `href="/home.php"` will make it `localhost/home.php` not `localhost/website/home.php`